# Running unit tests in parallel

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know if there is a way to run different [TestMethods] in Visual studio in parallel?

Comment: The Team Test team published a blog post about executing unit tests in parrallel on a multi-cpu/core machine few days ago. You can read the information you're looking for here : [http://blogs.msdn.com/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20190118141933/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpucore-machine/) Enjoy!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1):

[NUnit 2.5](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5) has an option to support running unit tests in parallel. That has nothing to do with the unit test framework that's built into VS, but it is possible to run NUnit tests inside VS, with the right plugin.

Answer (score -2):

MSTest in Visual Studio runs unit tests in parallel. When running tests VSTestHost (process that runs the unit tests) executes each unit test on a separate thread.

Comment: Unit tests are run on different threads in a non-deterministic order, but they are always sequentially ordered. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/84afa304-e652-4aba-98c2-be26dea928e4/

Comment: The "always sequentially ordered" restriction is obsolete.  See PatriceVB's answer above.