# Run Selenium MSTests in parallel from tfsbuild 2012

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, tfsbuild, selenium-grid

I have a suite of selenium tests that i want to run in parallel on our selenium grid from our tfs 2012 build. Is this possible to configure with mstest? If so how do I go about setting this up?

Comment: Does TFS support using a runsetting file? If you, you can use the legacy testsettings file to force it to run in parallel. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674606/can-visual-studio-2012-run-unit-tests-in-parallel/18090070#18090070

This is how it was done in vs2010, so you can google that to find more info about the testsettings file.