# How to execute tests in parallel using runsettings file on VS2013

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, runsettings

we have moved from VS2010 to VS2013 environment. Our solution has over 5K unit tests and on VS2010 they took about 5 minutes while on VS2013 they are taking about 20 minutes.

We saw that there is an issue using the `testsettings` file as it configures VS2013 to use the former test framework so we moved it to a `runsettings` file which in facts solves some problems we had on the transition.

The main think right now is that we cannot find how to configure VS2013 to execute the tests in parallel. On the former VS we had the   `<Execution parallelTestCount="0">` setting which seems to be non available on the `runsettings` file.

Summarizing, how can we run tests in parallel using a `runsettings` file so we use the newer framework?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio 2012 run unit tests in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674606/can-visual-studio-2012-run-unit-tests-in-parallel)

Comment: It is probably a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674606/can-visual-studio-2012-run-unit-tests-in-parallel :S

Answer (score 1):

You use   ?

You can force VS2013 to use the 2010-2013 test settings file. You can add FileName.testsettings into the 2013 .runsettings file.

```
<MSTest>
      <CaptureTraceOutput>True</CaptureTraceOutput>
      <DeploymentEnabled>false</DeploymentEnabled>
      <SettingsFile>FILENAME.testsettings</SettingsFile>
      <ForcedLegacyMode>True</ForcedLegacyMode>
</MSTest>
```

Comment: If you do that you are not using the newer framework and you switch to the old one (the one ran with MSText.exe) which has other issues. We need to use the new framework in parallel.