# VS2012 - Disable parallel test runs

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, parallel-processing

I've got some unit tests (c++) running in the Visual Studio 2012 test framework.

From what I can tell, the tests are running in parallel. In this case the tests are stepping on each other - I do not want to run them in parallel!

For example, I have two tests in which I have added breakpoints and they are hit in the following order:

1. Test1 TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE
2. Test2 TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE
3. Test2 TEST_METHOD
4. Test1 TEST_METHOD

If the init for Test1 runs first then all of its test methods should run to completion before anything related to Test2 is launched!

After doing some internet searches I am sufficiently confused. Everything I am reading says [Visual Studio 2012 does not run tests concurrently by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674606/can-visual-studio-2012-run-unit-tests-in-parallel), and you have to jump through hoops to enable it. We certainly have not enabled it in our project.

Any ideas on what could be happening? Am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something fundamental here?

**Yes.**
Your should never assume that another test case will work as expected. This means that it should *never* be a concern if the tests execute synchronously or asynchronously.

Of course there are test cases that expect some fundamental part code to work, this might be own code or a part of the framework/library you work with. When it comes to this, the programmer should know what data or object to expect as a result.

This is where [Mock Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650441.aspx) come into play. Mock objects allow you to mimic a part of code and assure that the object provides exactly what you expect, so you don't rely on other (time consuming) services, such as HTTP requests, file stream etc.
You can [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx).

When project becomes complex, the setup takes a fair number of lines and code starts duplicating. Solution to this are `Setup` and `TearDown` methods. The naming convention differs from framework to framework, `Setup` might be called `beforeEach` or `TestInitialize` and `TearDown` can also appear as `afterEach` or `TestCleanup`. Names for NUnit, MSTest and xUnit.net can be found on [xUnit.net codeplex page](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons).

---

**A simple example application:**

- it should read a config file
- it should verify if config file is valid
- it should update user's config

The way I would go about building and testing this:

- have a method to read config and second one to verify it
- have a getter/setter for user's settings
- test read method if it returns desired result (object, string or however you've designed it)
- create mock config which you're expecting from read method and test if method accepts it

  - at this point, you should create multiple mock configs, which test all possible scenarios to see if it works for all possible scenarios and fix it accordingly. This is also called [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage).
- create mock object of accepted config and use the setter to update user's config, then use to check if it was set correctly

This is a basic principle of [Test-Driven Development (TDD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

If the test suite is set up as described and all tests pass, all these parts, connected together, should work perfectly. Additional test, for example [End-to-End (E2E)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle) testing isn't necessarily needed, I use them only to assure that whole application flow works and to easily catch the error (e.g. http connection error).

Comment: While I think you have a lot of great things to say in this post - I disagree with the statement "it should never be a concern if the tests execute synchronously or asynchronously". How can I guarantee an expected state if I cannot control which tests are running asynchronously?

Comment: I have added an example, it might help you understand what is the idea of dependancy injection (mock objects).

Comment: I admire your tenacity, though I am still struggling to understand how all this relates to tests that run asynchronously. Therefore, I will ask again, how can I guarantee an expected state if I cannot control which tests are running asynchronously?

Comment: @dtmland I think maremp's point is that there shouldn't be any shared state between unit tests. If there is no shared state, then the expected state at any point in the test is deterministic regardless of whether or not the tests run synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you for explanation @Lilshieste, that's exactly what I wanted to explain.