# Is it possible to do Multi threading of Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

I have a some 500 unit tests. And there is a service created as soon as they are started. Presently a single service is created and used by all the tests. I want to apply multi threading to them, such that all the 500 tests would run concurrently. And if one of my thread(test) is logging out of the service it should not affect the service of the other test.

Is it possible to do it or I should have an independent service created for each of the threads.

Am using C# and Visual Studio 12.

I may be very vague with the question, but please put in your answers. At least provide any useful links.

Comment: Create a test that runs the other tests async?

Comment: What testing framework are you using (MSUnit, NUnit, etc)?

Comment: This thread covers using VS.net to run tests in parallel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674606/can-visual-studio-2012-run-unit-tests-in-parallel

Comment: What is preventing you from running the tests in parallel now? The project settings, test harness, or your service? The latter could be fixed with judicious application of DI and mocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good unit tests are supposed to be [independent of each other](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/10/qualities_good_test). They shouldn't share stateful resources (regarding your example, one can wonder if a stateful service that you can "log into" is a good idea in the first place). If you follow that approach, you should have no problem running your tests in parallel, as most of the modern test runners allow you to do.