# Test execution in parallel via visual studio, Tests are getting skipped

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I'm using VS2013, running 120 c# selenium tests, with a .testsetting file that contains the following parameters Execution parallelTestCount="5" and test timeout of 6000ms(6 seconds).
The tests duartion are more than 6 seconds, I used this configuration to reproduce the problem.
After 6 seconds 5 tests are failing and the rest are skipped.
This is what i'm getting in the output window:
"Test run is aborting on *Machine-Name*, number of hung tests exceeds maximum allowable '5'."

Testsettings file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TestSettings name="RemoteWebDriver" id="e293abd4-745a-43f5-a831-2064f9305fc6" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
      <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
      <Deployment>
        <DeploymentItem filename="TfsAutomation\testDefintionSources.config" />
        <DeploymentItem filename="TfsAutomation\TfsAutomationCore.config" />
      </Deployment>
      <Scripts setupScript="TestScriptRemoteWebDriver.bat" />
      <Execution parallelTestCount="5">
        <Timeouts runTimeout="10000000" testTimeout="6000" />
        <TestTypeSpecific>
          <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
            <AssemblyResolution>
              <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
            </AssemblyResolution>
          </UnitTestRunConfig>
        </TestTypeSpecific>
        <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
        </AgentRule>
      </Execution>
      <Properties />
    </TestSettings>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little inside of .testsetting and test code?

Comment: Are you using NUnit?

Answer (score 1):

This question has led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel) and was reading for while. It's worth mentioning that the internal structure of MsTest hasn't been change a lot since then a lot, at least according to the the reference above and my knowledge. I can only conclude the discussion saying **MSTest parallel mechanism isn't for UI testing in parallel** without knowing the internal structure the architecture of your test environment. Secondly, the **number of cores does matter in parallelism in MsTest parallel execution**. Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel) to see more about thread management. 
So, the question is what is the best solution then. Without having a lot of knowledge on MSTest but having enough knowledge on Selenium I would say **Selenium-Grid**. Let's grid control the parallel execution to be in safe side.