# parallel execution of tests in same class in mstest

Tags: mstest

I am trying to execute test cases in same class parallely using MStest framework.
I have used .runsettings(maxcpucount) file and testsettings(paralleltestcount) file but these are only running tests of different projects in parallel.I am unable to achieve this when I have tests in same class.

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: I want to run selenium tests against multiple browser in parallel

Comment: same situation here...sound like we need to create one project for each test which is so stupid....will not use this if this is a solution......Have a look at this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826137/unable-to-run-mstest-in-parallel-in-visual-studio-update1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this, by changing your run setting the following way. When you define the scope level to Method instead of ClassLevel, you would be able to run tests present in same class in parallel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- MSTest adapter -->
  <MSTest>
    <Parallelize>
      <Workers>10</Workers>
      <Scope>MethodLevel</Scope>
    </Parallelize>
  </MSTest

    >
    </RunSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run in-class tests in parallel using MSTest. Microsoft has this in their backlog tasks ([microsoft github](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/004-In-Assembly-Parallel-Execution.md)).

In the mean time you can use NUnit to achieve this. Try this blog: http://approache.com/blog/from-mstest-to-nunit/

Parallelization using NUnit with Selenium: Try this videos: [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Txhpzx4NkOA), [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18zrtO1l7EU)