# Unable to run mstest in parallel in Visual Studio Update1

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mstest

I am developing a MSTest framework based unit test project. The issue I have is I am not able to run the test in parallel and it is running sequentially. I have added the below line in my testsettings file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
   </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

and when I run the command

```
vstest.console.exe C:\Git\Test.dll /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Flow1|TestCategory=Flow2|TestCategory=Flow3" /settings:C:\Git\UIRunSettings.runsettings
```

the test are running one by one and not in parallel. Any thoughts would be much helpful.

**EDIT**
I believe I am facing the same issue as stated in the link.

https://johnkoerner.com/vs2015/parallel-test-execution-in-visual-studio-2015-update-1-might-not-be-what-you-expect/

But dont know whats the exact resolution the author proposes.

Is the test need to be run at the solution level? Any pointers would be much helpful

All the tests has been categorised and I am finding only the test mentioned in the TestcaseFilter getting picked up......Confused was what I need to do next?

Any MS guys, can you please help. I believe more documentation is necessary for the testing community rather than a one paragraph documentation about runsettings parallel run.

Can any body please let me know. Confused again by hearing the word containers and assemblies...DO I need to create a separate DLL for each of the test methods???

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to run them in parallel through the Unit Tests option in VS?

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set it in VS? I am not sure how to do it

Comment: In VS, goto `Test>Windows>Test Explorer` and when the Test Explorer opens up, just hit Run All tests

Comment: Ok...Will do it right away. Thanks

Comment: Its running one by one. Can you helpe me please

Comment: I believe I am facng the same issue as this link  https://johnkoerner.com/vs2015/parallel-test-execution-in-visual-studio-2015-update-1-might-not-be-what-you-expect/

Comment: Even I believe this is pointing to same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tests need to be in separate assemblies (DLLs) in order to be run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. I was looking into your website yesterday. So, just to confirm..What I need to do is generate separate DLLs for each of the test?  SInce this changes the whole framework and also wondering how the config will be ( for example vsconsole.test.exe command line etc...

Comment: Is there a way to run all tests within a project  in parallel using rnusettings?? Pls let me know

Comment: I think that one project per test is overkill.  As far as I know, there is no way to run tests within a given project in parallel.  There used to be support in mstest using testsettings file, but I haven't tried using that with the new vstest infrastructure.

Comment: @TimothyRajan I added some sample code here: https://github.com/johnkoerner/VS2015ParallelUnitTests , so you can more easily play with the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Marking your answer as a valid one. Heartful thanks.