# How to run multiple MSTest ( within the same project and in same class ) in Parallel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I am writing a test automation framework and I am in an situation where I need to execute all the unit test ( within a same project ) in parallel using the runsettings file.

Here I mean I have a class and I have multiple tests within the class and I need to run this parallel.

I have followed all steps dutifully but still not able to make it run parallel.

I am stuck here.. I have raised a question previously

[Unable to run mstest in parallel in Visual Studio Update1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826137/unable-to-run-mstest-in-parallel-in-visual-studio-update1)

Also, another question similar to mine

[parallel execution of tests in same class in mstest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468910/parallel-execution-of-tests-in-same-class-in-mstest?rq=1)

My confusion now is Do I need to create separate project for each of my tests to achieve parallelism

Am I missing to see something which is very obvious?

MSTest Parallel test functionality Developers please help me

Comment: even the (supposed to be) more advanced XUnit Framework does not support it. But obviously it will, if you split the Tests in different classes, which is at least a bit more handy than different assemblies https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSTest does not support running in parallel for tests in the same container. So, yes, you would have to write separate assemblies (DLLs) for tests that will run in parallel. I wouldn't say you should write one assembly per tests, as that would be overkill.

Perhaps you can find some logical grouping of tests that makes sense. Depending on the types of tests you run, you may only want 2-8 running in parallel.

If you want to test out the functionality of multiple tests across containers, I have a [blog post](https://johnkoerner.com/vs2015/parallel-test-execution-in-visual-studio-2015-update-1-might-not-be-what-you-expect/) and a github [sample project](https://github.com/johnkoerner/VS2015ParallelUnitTests) that demonstrate this.

Comment: Thanks  a lot John.

Comment: I was not aware of this before. Thx for bringing in some light.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `vstest.console.exe` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx instead of MSTEST.
Personally I ran into trouble using MSTEST in remote Powershell session, but VSTEST runs fine.
Ensure your tests are thread-safe!!

define the amount of parallelism with `parallelTestCount` in the .testSettings file

Also check for reference the how TFS or TSTS does the call to vstest with the option to run in parallel:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/VSTest.ps1

Comment: I agree with you... I am running using vstest.console.exe. Still, I am facing the issue....When I run using vstest.console.exe in cmd prompt locally also, I am experiencing the same behaviour. Can you please share me a sample vstest.console.exe cmd line which you have used in your project ( with all confidential info obfusctaed) Thanks for your help

Comment: your post  made me happy.

Comment: Also, I believe when I run the test in TFS, it is invoking the whole test execution in vstest.console.exe. I can see this in the build logs

Comment: Also, I have checked the option run in Parallel in TFS.

Comment: Doesnt it work with TFS in parallel? How Do you verify?

Comment: I checked the Run Parallel option in TFS Build task and ran it...It was not running in parallel

Comment: how do you verify it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, by changing your run setting the following way. When you define the scope level to Method instead of ClassLevel, you would be able to run tests present in same class in parallel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- MSTest adapter -->
  <MSTest>
    <Parallelize>
      <Workers>10</Workers>
      <Scope>MethodLevel</Scope>
    </Parallelize>
  </MSTest>
    </RunSettings>
```