# In MSTest, how can I specify that certain test methods cannot be run in parallel with each other?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I have a large set of integration tests that test a website server. Most of these tests are fine to run in parallel. However, I have a few that change settings and can cause each other to fail when run in parallel.

As a simplified example, let's say I had these tests:

```
TestPrice_5PercentTax
TestPrice_10PercentTax
TestPrice_NoTax
TestInventory_Add10Items
TestInventory_Remove10Items
```

The inventory tests will not get in the way of each other, and are not affected by the price tests. But the price tests will change the `Tax` setting, so that if both `5` and `10` run in parallel, `10` could end up changing the setting before `5` is done, and `5` would fail because it saw 10% tax instead of the 5% it expected.

I want to define a category for the three price tests, and say that they may not run at the same time as one another. They can run at the same time as any other tests, just not the other price tests. Is there a way to do this in MSTest?

Comment: Create a single test method and call the conflicting tests inside that, not from MSTest.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution for me because if `TestPrice_5PercentTax` fails, the rest of the tests will not be run. I do not want to lose information about the rest if one breaks.

Comment: Depending on how you initiate MSTest, the easiest solution would probably be to add a clause like @DourHighArch is recommending. 
Either by splitting the specific tests to run alone by using tools likely found in the test framework you are using. Or using a method to call the specified tests that conflict with parallelism.
Run the specified tests with a separate task/method depending on how your initialization is performed.
I have only encountered the same issue with VsTest in a buildserver enviroment, so my comment may not be accurate for this particular solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MsTest v2 has functionality as following

```
[assembly: Parallelize(Workers = 0, Scope = ExecutionScope.MethodLevel)]
// Notice the assembly bracket, this can be compatible or incompatible with how your code is built

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestClass1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [DoNotParallelize] // This test will not be run in parallel
        public void TestPrice_5PercentTax() => //YourTestHere?;

        [TestMethod]
        [DoNotParallelize] // This test will not be run in parallel
        public void TestPrice_10PercentTax() => //YourTestHere?;            

        [TestMethod]
        [DoNotParallelize] // This test will not be run in parallel
        public void TestPrice_NoTax() => //YourTestHere?;

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestInventory_Add10Items() => //YourTestHere?;

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestInventory_Remove10Items() => //YourTestHere?;
    }
}
```

More detailed information can be found here [MSTest v2 at meziantou.net](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-execute-tests-in-parallel.htm)

I strongly recommend atleast a quick read through of the link, as this will likely help you solve and understand the issue with the tests run in parallel or sequential.

Comment: That's not quite as customizable as I would have liked, but I guess I am looking for something that MSTest just doesn't offer. I ended up using this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)  Most things can be achieved, but as you stated in the solution reply. More advanced approaches often requires more time than it's worth to invest for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to provide a potential solution that I started but did not pursue.

First, I made a class that I could use as an attribute on my test methods.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple =true)]
public class NoParallel : Attribute
{
    public NoParallel(string nonParallelGroupName)
    {
        SetName = nonParallelGroupName;
    }

    public string SetName { get; }
}
```

Then I went and added it to my test methods that will conflict.

```
[NoParallel("Tax")]
public void TestPrice_5PercentTax();

[NoParallel("Tax")]
public void TestPrice_10PercentTax();

[NoParallel("Tax")]
public void TestPrice_NoTax();

// This test doesn't care
public void TestInventory_Add10Items();

// This test doesn't care
public void TestInventory_Remove10Items();
```

I gave my test class a static dictionary of mutexes keyed by their names.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Mutex> exclusiveCategories = new Dictionary<string, Mutex>();
```

Finally, using a helper to grab all of the "NoParallel" strings the test method has...

```
public static List<string> NonparallelSets(this TestContext context, ContextHandler testInstance)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var testName = context.TestName;
    var testClassType = testInstance.GetType();
    var testMethod = testClassType.GetMethod(testName);

    if (testMethod != null)
    {
        var nonParallelGroup = testMethod.GetCustomAttribute<NoParallel>(true);

        if (nonParallelGroup != null)
        {
            result = nonParallelGroups.Select(x => x.SetName).ToList();
        }
    }

    result.Sort();
    return result;
}
```

... I set up a TestInitialize and TestCleanup to make the tests with matching NoParallel strings execute in order.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void PerformSetup()
{
    // Get all "NoParallel" strings on the test method currently being run
    var nonParallelSets = testContext.NonparallelSets(this);

    // A test can have multiple "NoParallel" attributes so do this for all of them
    foreach (var setName in nonParallelSets)
    {
        // If this NoParallel set doesn't have a mutex yet, make one
        Mutex mutex;
        if (exclusiveCategories.ContainsKey(setName))
        {
            mutex = exclusiveCategories[setName];
        }
        else
        {
            mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex();
            exclusiveCategories[setName] = mutex;
        }

        // Wait for the mutex before you can run the test
        mutex.WaitOne();
    }
}

[TestCleanup]
public void PerformTeardown()
{
    // Get the "NoParallel" strings on the test method again
    var nonParallelSets = testContext.NonparallelSets(this);

    // Release the mutex held for each one
    foreach (var setName in nonParallelSets)
    {
        var mutex = exclusiveCategories[setName];
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

We decided not to pursue this because it wasn't really worth the effort. Ultimately we decided to pull the tests that can't run together into their own test class, and mark them with `[DoNotParallelize]` as H.N suggested.