# Can I prevent Visual Studio from interleaving my Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I recently joined a new team and am having trouble running the pre-existing unit-tests.

There are two `[TestClass]`, "TestA" and "TestB", each with 30 individual `[TestMethod]`

Where things get finnicky is that both "TestA" and "TestB" have a `[ClassInitialize]` method that prepares an external environment for their tests -- specifically, they clear then write a file to an external folder.

When my teammembers run the tests, they observe the following:

1. "TestA" Initializes, sets the external file to "A", and runs its 30 unit tests. They all pass.
2. "TestB" Initializes, sets the external file to "B" (deleting "A" in the process), and runs its 30 unit tests. They all pass.

However, when *I* run the tests locally, I observe the following:

1. "TestA" Initializes, sets the external file to "A", and runs 7 unit tests. They pass.
2. "TestB" Initializes, sets the external file to "B", and runs 11 unit tests. They pass.
3. The other 23 "TestA" unit tests run. They fail, since the external file they require no longer exists.
4. The other 19 "TestB" unit tests run. They pass.

Is there a way I can rewrite these tests to ensure that all methods on a `[TestClass]` get run before switching to a different `[TestClass]`? I don't need the 30 individual test cases to run in a specific order, I just need **all** of "TestA" to run before "TestB" is allowed to start running its tests.

Is this some setting in Visual Studio (I'm using 2017)? I can't fathom why every other member on the team can run the `[TestClass]`s serially while mine run interleaved.

**Edit:** I have spent a few days playing around with this in my spare time and... it makes absolutely no sense to me.

If I open VS and immediately run the tests, they run in a per-class order, just as I want.

After running any test run, subsequent test runs are interleaved, and in a non-random order. (e.g., it always runs TestA 4,7,9; TestB 2, 1, 5; Test A 3, 5...)

**Why on earth would the first test run be processed differently!?** And more importantly, how do I make it so subsequent test runs are the same as the first?

Comment: I found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel - looks to be related, maybe an answer there can help you reverse engineer it

Comment: Thanks, but not quite sure it is? -- I don't care if the tests run serially or in parallel; I just need them *batched*.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I do believe Charleh is right. Most likely your tests are setup to run parallel to each other. Your setup might differ from that of your coworkers and they are running them one after the other. Furthermore, just note that it is bad design and bad practice for your test to be failing if they are not ran in order. You should take a look at the 'i' in the F.I.R.S.T. acronym.

Comment: @RavenDreamer does it always 100% run 7 A tests, then 11 B tests or is it sometimes 6 or 8? It sounds like your tests are running in parallel. Try putting a thread sleep for half a second in one of the test fixtures - that will at least cause enough of a delay to determine if you are getting deterministic execution or not.

Comment: @Charleh The tests are not running in parallel - if I have a breakpoint in one of the A tests, none of the B tests are ever run. (Until I "Continue", anyway). I will check if the order the individual test methods run is invariant or not.

Comment: @Sebastien The tests don't depend on one another - they depend on the `ClassInitialize` of **another test class** waiting until the first class' test methods have run. Is that not a reasonable practice?

Comment: Yes, test fixtures should be self contained and since you are correctly setting up state in `ClassInitialize` I'd say your tests are reasonable (without seeing the implementation). However, the fact that one test runs interleaved with another suggests they are running in parallel, but even if they aren't it might be that tests sometimes run like this and I've not run into it before. Can your tests not run in parallel/unordered by writing this required file to a temporary filename instead of a fixed one? I suppose it depends on your implementation.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information from my research. The truth is only more confusing, however.