# How to run test sequences in new MSTests?

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

How to run test sequences in new MSTests?
I have code like this:

```
        [TestMethod, Priority(1)]
        public void Test1()
        {
           //do something
        }

        [TestMethod, Priority(2)]
        public void Test2()
        {
           //do something
        }
```

but the tests run parallel, I want to run the tests one by one because these tests call the same method. Priority doesn't work.

Comment: First, I'm not sure but I don't think you're using the `Priority` correctly. Second, are you trying to establish order of execution or deal with dependent tests? That's probably not a great idea.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your use case? Why do you need to run the tests in a specific order? This feels to me like it could be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: tests should be totally independent of each other, and able to run in whatever order IMO

Comment: Are your tests async? I believe async is the only way MSTest will execute in parallel.  Based on your sample code, MSTest will execute these tests in series.

Comment: Tests SHOULD be independent of one another, but this is not always possible - e.g. environment variables, configuration files, etc. Meaning if tests are running at the same time on a CI server for example, unexpected issues may occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this anwer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908731/66207), you can see that you can also disable parallel execution for a specific test using `[DoNotParallelize]` on a test method.

Answer (score 0):

The default test order in MSTest is alphabetically by test name. You must disable running tests in parallel using either the toggle button in the Visual Studio Test Explorer or by using a runsettings file. Disabling running in parallel will not necessarily run tests in a specific order, it only guarantees that tests will be run sequentially.

It is best practice to *not* create tests that need to run in a specific order, but there are still ways to do this. You can refer to the examples here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/order-unit-tests?pivots=mstest