# Visual Studio 2017 15.5 Parallel Unit Tests with Code Coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, vs-unit-testing-framework

We've been running unit tests in parallel for several years (both with and without code coverage), following the instructions here:
[How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)
and here:
[Running unit tests in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921953/running-unit-tests-in-parallel)

However, recent updates to Visual Studio 2017, (versions 15.5.0 or 15.5.1 and later) seem to have broken this, and I get the following error now whenever I try to use a custom test settings file and also do a code coverage analysis:

```
[12/29/2017 1:35:10 PM Error] Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.SettingsException: Data collectors configured via run settings are not supported with embedded test settings. Please see https://aka.ms/vstest-configure-datacollector for more information. Run settings:
```

I have updated, rebooted, and verified this issue on another system.

When reverting to default settings (no custom test settings file) and using the 'Run Tests in Parallel' button introduced in VS 2015 update 2, it seems to simply ignore the button setting and run the tests serially (whether you do code coverage or not).

I looked into the link provided in the error (https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md), but it did little to help clarify the issue, other than possibly indicate that yes, a change was made.

If I turn off the custom settings file, the tests run just fine, but they take about 7x as long to run, which is very frustrating.

How does one get parallel unit test execution working in VS 2017 15.5+?

Comment: I came here to ask the same question. This JUST started happening after updating from VS2017 15.4.x to 15.5.x

I've found no answers or even clues so far in googling... I look forward to anyone having ANY ideas on how to get around this.

Comment: Given the lack of response here, I've reported this issue to Microsoft.  Please vote for this issue if it's affecting you too: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/176972/unit-tests-with-code-coverage-no-longer-able-to-ru.html

Comment: I have another issue where they've (without warning that I ever saw) completely broke MSTest V1 tests... I've entered the problem report here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/176422/new-error-in-155-data-collectors-configured-via-ru.html